# Location static CSS in NGINX

Tags: css, nginx, static

I can’t get my static css file through nginx on my server.

This is my nginx file configuration :

`server {

```
listen 80;

root /home/root/toolbox/src;

location /static {
    alias /home/root/toolbox/src/toolbox/static/css;
}

location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}
```

}
`

My css file is in the folder css : /home/root/toolbox/src/toolbox/static/css

I tried different path like : /home/root/toolbox/src/toolbox/static/ or /home/root/toolbox/src/toolbox/

It's not working :(

Any idea ?

Thx !

Comment: What is the URL for the static resource? Check the access log and error log for details.

Comment: I have this error in log :
[error] 17884#17884: *8 open() "/home/root/toolbox/src/toolbox/static/css/style.css" failed (2: No such file or directory) 



But the path is correct : /root/toolbox/src/toolbox/static/css/style.css

Comment: Now i had this error : failed (13: Permission denied)

Comment: The process running Nginx needs read access to the files **and every directory** in the path.

Comment: How can i allow nginx in read access to the file ?